# Apply a condition only on image which is nil Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to Rails so my code is probably ugly..

I have a loop which give me the 3 latest `articles` on my index page.

I added a condition to say "*if there is no image in my article, give me a image from unsplash*".

**The issue is : that's apply the condition on the 3 images even if 2 of 3 images exists. I want that only the image which is nil get the unsplash image.
How can I do that ?**

```
<% @articles.last(3).in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% group.each do |article| %>
        <% if article.image.exists? %>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
              <style media>
                .card { background: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(30,30,30,0.6) 30%, rgba(46,46,46,0.5) 80%), url("<%= article.image.url(:medium) %>"); }
              </style>
              <img src="<%= article.user.image.url(:thumb) %>" alt="" class="avatar-small card-user">
              <div class="card-description">
                <a href="<%= articles_path(article.slug) %>"><h3><%= article.title %></h3></a>
                <p><%= truncate(article.subtitle, length: 45, escape: false) %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
     <% else %>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="card">
              <style media>
                .card { background: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(30,30,30,0.6) 30%, rgba(46,46,46,0.5) 80%), url("http://unsplash.it/1280/500/?random"); }
              </style>
              <img src="<%= article.user.image.url(:thumb) %>" alt="" class="avatar-small card-user">
              <div class="card-description">
                <a href="<%= articles_path(article.slug) %>"><h3><%= article.title %></h3></a>
                <p><%= truncate(article.subtitle, length: 45, escape: false) %></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

my controller :

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @articles = Article.last(3)
  end
end
```

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: try `article.image.nil?` in place of `article.image.exists?`

Comment: Nothing change with .nil? .. I still have 3 unsplash images while only one image is nil.

Comment: not sure how you setting up your image model, try `article.try(:image).try(:url)` ?

Comment: Can you try this on console to get what you are getting on calling `article.image` and `article.image.exists?`

Comment: I get : `> Article.image NoMethodError: undefined method image' for #<Class:0x007fb98f819598>`

Answer (score 0):

I finally find the error.

It was `<style media>` which was the issue.

I finally do this :

```
<% @articles.last(3).in_groups_of(3, false).each do |group| %>
    <div class="row">
      <% group.each do |article| %>
          <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
              <a href="<%= articles_path(article.slug) %>"><div style="background: linear-gradient(-225deg, rgba(30,30,30,0.6) 30%, rgba(46,46,46,0.5) 80%), url('<%= article.image.url(:thumb) %>');" class="card">
                <img src="<%= article.user.image.url(:thumb) %>" alt="" class="avatar-small card-user">
              <div class="card-description">
                <h3><%= article.title %></h3>
                <p><%= truncate(article.soustitre, length: 45, escape: false) %></p>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div></a>
        <% end %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
```

Now the 3 latest articles are displayed on my index page. 
I add a default image with paperclip and withdrawed the condition `if else`.