# What is the purpose of nil? and exists? methods in ruby/rails conditions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, if-statement

I often (very often) see code like this in the conditions:

```
<% catalog.each do |article| %>
  <% if article.image.nil? %>
    ...
```

or (e.g. [seen there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38832543/apply-a-condition-only-on-image-which-is-nil-rails-4))

```
<% catalog.each do |article| %>
  <% if article.image.exists? %>
    ...
```

However we all know that **nil** interprets like **false** in the conditions. ActiveRecord query returns nil if nothing found.

Why not simply write:

`<% unless article.image %>`
(unless there is article do something)

instead of

`<% if article.image.nil? %>`
(if there is nothing at article.image do something)

and

`<% if article.image %>` instead of `<% if article.image.exists? %>`

I usually write the code without `nil?` and `exists?`. What am I missing? Is there any pitfalls?

Comment: as a note `nil?` and `exists?` are very different. `exists?` is a `rails` query method and can have additional conditions passed to it similar to `where` query conditions. Also the query created is very different as well `exists?` will generate a query like `SELECT 1 FROM table_name WHERE conditions` rather than `SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE conditions` this can be far more efficient when the record actually exists because it does not actually create an `ActiveRecord` object but rather just returns `true` or `false`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, and in many typical RESTful Rails patterns, you're correct that using the implicit version is identical in behavior.

But there are certainly suations where `nil?` and `exists?` are necessary and/or more readable...

For instance, **`nil?`** is the only option when you're reading a boolean attribute, and you need different behavior for `false` vs `nil` (since both are falsey in Ruby).

Or, assume in your example, that each `Article` has many images, and you define a method to get an `Article`'s first image according to display order:

```
def primary_image
  images.order(display_order: "ASC").limit(1)
end
```

In this case, if your `Article` doesn't have any images, `primary_image` will return an empty collection, which  is truthy. So, in this case, you'd need to use **`exists?`** (or `present?`). Rails provides several convenience methods for checking data records.

*(or make sure the `primary_image` method returns `nil` or `false` when the collection is empty)*

Comment: Thank you for a good explanation!
Rails also has some methods to check whether collection is empty or not. I mean `blank?` and `present?`

Comment: You're correct @user1201917, thanks for pointing that out (I updated the answer)

Comment: Another note...I purposely used `limit(1)`, in my example, because it returns an empty collection if no records are found. However, the more appropriate `first` method actually returns `nil` if no record is found, which would end up being the correct implicit behavior anyway. Further supports that most patterns work just fine with implicit checks.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I rarely use either one of them. Like you suggested, I mostly just use `if` or `unless` depends on the situation without bothering with `nil?` or `exists?`

As for the difference between the two:

`nil?` is a **Ruby** method to see whether the object is nil or not.

[`exists?`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/exists%3F/class) is a **Rails** method to see whether the record exists in the database

I guess, just use whichever is more efficient. I have been trying to convert my codes to use [`try`](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) to avoid no method error.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I use `try` to avoid no method error too.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time it's just to be more explicit I suppose.

In your example above it doesn't matter if you check explicitly or implicitly.

But if you want to check explicitly for `nil` for example, you use the `#nil?` because sometimes you want to react differently if `false` is returned.

As an example: `false` and `nil` are often not interchangeable for boolean values in a database.

Like @lusketeer already said is `nil?` a method of the ruby standard library and `exists?` a method of the Rails framework.

But I think almost always you are good with the implicit way.

Comment: Thanks! You dispelled my doubts about implicity.